# Genetics and Heredogram - Proving the teacher is wrong

Tags: genetics

I want serious help here. I'm in first year of medical school and I jut had my second test in Genetics. One question of the test gave us a heredogram and asked us what was the most probable type of genetic disease the family had. There were 2 types of disease that would fit the heredogram. Recessive autosomal and Dominant X-linked. I put both and explained why both them fit. But a lot of my colleagues put only one of them. He said after that he wanted X-linked, because the heredogram had more trends of X-linked diseases. I just don't bite that. This is not the way we calculate probability. For example a autosomal disease can happen in 44 out of the 46 chromosomes while the X-linked only in the X chromossome (1.5 in average). Also, what if recessive diseases are more common than dominant. What if most of the people with X-linked diseases are infertile or if most of them dies. All of these reduces the chance of a given heredogram being Dominant X-linked. We can't say something one based on the trends.

The heredogram is the below.

[image]

Do you agree with me? I really need some opinions of other people so we can contest the teacher. Otherwise half of the classroom will get a zero.

Comment: This site does not exist to give opinions so people can contest their teachers. It exists to provide objective answers to problems of biology which are of general importance and interest. The title shows a particular petty arrogance which is more likely to antagonise people than gain their sympathy.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are making this too complicated. You don't have enough data from this diagram to make any sort of rigorous statistical judgement. You are just looking for clues.

Note that in the first generation offspring of the affected male founder, **all** the female offspring are affected and **none** of the male offspring are affected. This is exactly the pattern you would expect for a dominant X-linked trait.

For an autosomal recessive trait, you'd expect roughly equal numbers of male and female offspring to be affected in the first generation where once parent is affected and the other is a carrier. This is true regardless of all the red herrings you raise about the number of autosomes, fertility, and lethality. So this is a little odd looking for an autosomal recessive trait. It's a tiny sample size, so not impossible, not definitively ruled out, just a little unlikely.

Diagrams like this don't usually give you a definitive result, but they can indicate where to start looking.

Comment: In my opinion, we cannot say autosomal recessive is more unlikely. Consider the first and second generation only for example. An affected father, a non-affected mother, 3 affected daughters and a non affected son. Given the disease is Dominant X-linked the chance of the parents have that children is (1/2)^4=1/16. While if the disease was autosomal recessive (1/4)^4 = 1/256, that is 16 times less. But consider an Dominant X-linked disease is 23 times less common than an autosomal (what could be completely true given the number of chromosomes). Than now autosomal is MORE LIKELY than X-linked.

Comment: @JoãoMaldonado No, you are miscalculating the likelihoods. The likelihood of the data given the Dominant X-Linked model is exactly 1. For the first generation of offspring for an affected father and unaffected mother, the female children are necessarily affected, and the male offspring are necessarily unaffected. No other pattern is possible.

Comment: For the autosomal recessive model, the father must be carrying two copies of the recessive mutation and the mother must be a carrier, with one copy of the recessive mutation. The status of each of their offspring is essentially a coin flip depending on which copy they inherit from the mother, so the likelihood of the observed 1st generation is (1/2)^4=0.0625. You may have a point that somatic chromosomes outnumber sex chromosomes, so that might boost the likelihood a little (this is called a prior), but it isn't going to be as simple as multiplying the likelihood by 23.

Comment: I’m not saying it is that simple. Just that it is not correct to say that X linked is more likely for sure. Also, you misunderstood the probability I calculated. The question is: what is the probability that an affected father and a non-affected mother have 4 children, 3 females affected and one male not affected.

Comment: If the disease is Dominant X-linked there is a likelihood of 50% of a random children be a female affected and 50% of the children be a male not affected. So the probability of that couple have 4 children with the pattern said above is 1/16. If the disease is recessive autosomal there is 25% of a ta from children be female affected, 25% female not affected, 25% male affected, 25% male not affected. The probability of the couple have tha 4 children as I said is 1/256

Comment: Also. If we have the statistic # people in that community (or the world considering the distribution is uniform) with autosomal recessive diseases divided by # of people with X linked dominant diseases and we consider and we consider both types of diseases live the same, have the same probability of finding a couple or having a fertile child etc. Then it would be as simple as multiplying this number to the 1/16 we calculated. Of course it is not like this. People with X linked diseases could be more or less fertile or find more or less couples or having more or less fertile children and etc.

Comment: My point is that no one can say that one disease is more likely than the other or ask that in a test. Inferring the mode of disease is something extremely complicated and by what I searched is only done with algorithms and computers, that calculate an error of the estimate, because neither them can say for sure what it is. So asking that in a test is very questionable, what he could have asked is to say what types of diseases would fit that heredogram or ask for only one of them, considering that more than one are possible to answer.

Comment: "The question is: what is the probability that an affected father and a non-affected mother have 4 children, 3 females affected and one male not affected" No, you're calculating the wrong thing. All we're interested in here is the probability of observing the disease or not given the inheritance model. The genders of the offspring are treated as a given for the purposes of this estimation.  I'd suggest that you review this material with your professor, because you're working from some fundamental misunderstandings.

Comment: I really doubt I’m misunderstanding statistics, I can be misunderstanding genetics. I’m already graduated in bot Mechanical Engineering and Math. The point for me using the sex into consideration was t standardize the ratio. I’m not concerned in the probability of that heredogram being autosomal recessive, but the ratio of the probability of it being autosomal recessive divides by the probability of it being Dominant X linked, i.e. how many times it is more likely that the given disease is autosomal recessive considering to the other option, based only on that heredogram

Comment: And as we HAVE to use the sex when we thread X linked diseases, we also have to use with the autosomal to calculate that ratio. If the sex weren’t important they would just vanish when the ratio is calculated. I’m not concerned with the 1/16 or the 1/256. But with the ratio (1/256)/(1/16) = 1/16 (by coincidence). You calculated the same ratio as I.

Comment: If you really want to understand why I calculated that way consider just a couple with an affected male having only one child, female and affected. Let’s make the question: What is the chance of this heredogram be referring to a Dominant X linked disease. Answer: Probability of the disease in the male population multiplied by the probability of males with that type of disease find a couple, multiplied by the probability of couples with an affected male with that disease have a living child, multiplied by the chance of that child be female, multiplied by the chance of that child be affected.

Comment: Then you divide trust  by the Probability of all genetic diseases in the male population multiplied by the probability of males with an type of genetic disease find a couple, multiplied by the probability of couples with an affected male with any genetic disease have a living child, multiplied by the chance of that child be female, multiplied by the chance of that child be affected with the same disease

Comment: Sorry but you are misunderstanding statistics at least as involved in interpreting the diagram. In formal terms we're using the diagram to do a maximum likelihood test to choose between two models. You assume one model, calculate the probability of the observed pattern of disease given model, then assume the other model and calculate the probability of the observed pattern of disease. The probability of the observed pattern of disease given a model is called the likelihood. You choose the model with the greater likelihood. No need to take ratios.

Comment: You are introducing a host of complications that are unneeded for this question. Given two models we're simply asking which model "better" explains the data right in front of us.  Check out any text on statistical genetics and really, please talk to your professor.

Comment: You can do that, you can calculate the probability only based on the disease model or pattern. But as I said, there are more things involved. A more complete estimation is the one I presented above, where we have to know many other things beside the disease pattern . If you calculated 2 likelihoods and both of them are 50% the you would say they are equally likely? No.  What you can say is: Considering both diseases are equally frequent in the population and all affected have the same life standard and life expectation and all other important things, then now they are equally likely

Comment: But if the frequency of one disease in the population in greater than the other than the chance of that heredogram being refereeing to this disease is greater as well.

Comment: You are introducing a host of complications that are unneeded for this question. Given two models we're simply asking which model "better" explains the data right in front of us.  Check out any text on statistical genetics and really, please talk to your professor. I hate to engage in credentialism, but you started it: Me: MS Applied Math and 15 years working as a bioinformatics programmer, and of course your professor is presumably a trained geneticist, so they "outrank" us both. Of course, I could be wrong, but so far it's two against one. Seriously, consider that you may be wrong.

Comment: I think neither one of us are wrong, we are just calculating different things. You calculated which model fit better. You did that 100% right. But the question was not which model fits better but whic disease type is more likely. These are different things. Let’s finish this topic with me presenting you a different question. Suppose we discover another type of genetic disease model that affects only 7 people in the role world. All the affected are female and they have only female daughters. All the daughters are blond, blind, have septum deviation and die before 30 years ild

Comment: On a pragmatic basis, statistics is the art of making decisions in the face of uncertainty. Many of the complicating factors you added are simply unknown, or even unknowable. Faced with a patient in the clinic you have to do the best you can with the limited facts you have: the pattern of inheritance in the family tree. As I said, it's not a definitive test, but it gives you a place to start looking.

Comment: Then you as a geneticist see a random heredogram. There is an affected mother, a non affected father, and 4 female daughters that are bold, blind, have septum deviation and died at 20 years old. By what you said I would say the new X disease model is the one that fits the best right? But is it more likely?